# How to get a 96 hour transit visa in Dubai?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, dubai

I am an Indian citizen with a US visa travelling to Canada and I have an 86 hour layover in Dubai.

- Is it possible to get a 96 hour transit visa upon arrival at Dubai airport?
- If so, how do I go about getting one?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visa-information/?

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain the 96 hour transit visa in advance through your UAE-based airline. If you have booked with Emirates, you can apply for it online by going to [Manage your booking](https://www.emirates.com/ae/english/manage-booking/). Etihad has a [dedicated web page for visas](https://uaevisas.etihad.com/echannels/web/client/etihad/index.html#/dashboard?lang=en). If you booked with flydubai, you can apply for it at the [nearest flydubai travel shop](https://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/visas-and-passports/uae-visas) which provides the service. They do not have online booking of the visa yet.

Note that entering with the 96 hour visa requires a 6 month validity on your passport.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to obtain the 96-hour transit visa upon arrival at Dubai Airport.
You can obtain a transit visa from Emirates Airlines or Etihad Airlines.
For more information, you can visit this website[Transit visa - The Official Portal of the UAE Government](https://government.ae/en/information-and-services/visiting-and-exploring-the-uae/transit-visa)